# Generating a map from a shapefile using ms4w mapserver

Tags: shapefile, cartography, mapserver, ms4w

I am trying to generate a map from a shapefie. Through some initial searching, I wrote the code below but I am getting just a white page.

Below is my code:

```
 MAP
# To enter comments into a mapfile add a # symbol at the beginning of the line

NAME parcels1_map
STATUS ON
SIZE 800 800
EXTENT 489885 5450946 490904 5451637
UNITS METERS
SHAPEPATH "shapefiles"
IMAGECOLOR 255 255 255

WEB
TEMPLATE "template.html"
IMAGEPATH "C:/ms4w/Apache/htdocs/siya/output/"
IMAGEURL "siya/output/"
END

LAYER
NAME "parcel1_boundaries"
DATA states
STATUS DEFAULT
TYPE POLYGON
CLASS
NAME "parcels1_color"
COLOR 255 215 0
END
END
 # end of map file
END
```

Comment: Add DEBUG 5 to your mapfile (after MAP), then try again. Do you get any errors reported?

Comment: i did not get any errors....iam able to get the image but its just blank

Comment: @PolyGeo  I looked at the accepted answer given in the _duplicate question_  Are you sure the question is a duplicate?

Comment: Your minimal mapfile can show a map but there is much that can go wrong. To start with, what is the projection and extents of "states"? You can check those with ogrinfo tool.

Comment: I produce map for the same shapefile using js its working fine.But with the above code its not working.and also i downloaded sample shape files from net and tryed that one also but no luck